# FIlling dataframe in a for loop in R

Tags: r

Please help me with the following:
I want my dataframe to have two columns. First column should contain the name of the variable while the second one should contain the total value of correlation of this variable with the other variables.
Then I want to sort this to find variables which have the total correlation highest comparing to the others. I correctly calculated total correlation for each variable.
**Unfortunately my code gives list and I can't sort it.**

```
korelacje <- data.frame(zmienna = character(),
                 wartosc = double(),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
n<-82
for (j in 1:n){
krl=0
for (i in 1:n){
  krl=krl+abs(cor(mbank[,j],mbank[,i]))
}

obs<-data.frame(zmienna = colnames(mbank)[j],wartosc = krl-1)
korelacje=rbind(korelacje, obs)

}
```

Here the resulting dataframe is not correct: [the name of the second column is the first observation and the names of the observations are in description column instead of 1,2,3...,82 which is very strange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DC4c.png)
I was trying also with this code, but it also gave me incorrect result:

```
korelacje <- data.frame()
n<-82

for (j in 1:82){
  krl=0
  for (i in 1:82){
    krl=krl+abs(cor(mbank[,j],mbank[,i]))
  }
  
  korelacje[j,1]= colnames(mbank)[j]
  korelacje[j,2]= krl-1

  
}
```

The above code results in dataframe which has two [columns duplicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd0ml.png)

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: If you want to use `cor` you could apply on the whole data as `cor(mtcars)` - `cor1 <- cor(mtcars);colnames(cor1)[max.col(replace(cor1, diag(cor1), -Inf), "first")]`

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: When I try to copy the output from dput to the comment is unfortunately to long.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem differently:

```
n<-82
X <- vector(mode="character", length=n)
Y <- vector(mode="numeric", length=n)


for (j in 1:n){
  krl=0
  for (i in 1:n){
    krl=krl+abs(cor(mbank[,j],mbank[,i]))
  }
  
  X[j]= colnames(mbank)[j]
  Y[j]= krl-1

  
}

korelacje <- data.frame(zmienna=X,wartosc=Y)

x<-korelacje[order(Y),]
```